# How to create a regex escaped so that it represent a normal string?

Tags: regex, string, scala

While looking for ways how can I count occurrences of a string in a long string I have found [one variant](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Count_occurrences_of_a_substring#Using_Regular_Expressions) which seems nice to me:

```
def countSubstring(str:String, substr:String) = substr.r.findAllMatchIn(str).length
```

Now what I have is not a regular expression, only an ordinary string. Is there some way how can I easily convert a string into a regex so that it matches the same way the original string would match like when using `String.contains`?

Example: The string to match might be `"Do I (really) want to match? Yes, I do."`. This needs to be escaped to serve as regex which matches the original string.

*Note: Consider substring counting as an example only - I know this particular case can be solved in other way, but there are more functions expecting regex input and being able to pass ordinary string into them might be usefull.*

Comment: Not sure what this means: `Is there some way how can I easily convert a string into a regex so that it matches the original string?` as you already seem to be doing that, but if you want to handle both regex and string inputs, why not just overload the `countSubstring` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to @Dima's answer, you could use the built in scala Regex `quote`:

```
def countSubstring(str:String, substr:String) = Regex.quote(substr).r.findAllMatchIn(str).length
```

Comment: Knowing the answer it was easy to find this was already asked before (and answered almost the same way).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(substr)` ... which is, actually, the same as `s"""\Q$substr\E"""`

Also, regex may not be the optimal tool for a task like this. You can count those substrings fairly easily with something like:

```
Iterator(str.indexOf(substr)){ n => str.indexOf(substr, n+1)
 .takeWhile(_ >= 0)
 .count(_ => true)
```

Comment: Ah! beat me to it :)

Comment: Are there any guarantees Scala Regex uses the same regex syntax as Java does (on JVM)? Is there some alternative available for Scala.js?

Comment: Scala does use the same regex engine as java. No idea about Scala.js